# tranpose specific columns in data frame

Tags: r, reshape, transpose

I have dataset that looks like below:

```
customerid  product store   Date    Sales
1   A   X1  1/2/2013    4
1   B   x2  1/9/2013    4
1   A   x2  1/9/2013    4
1   C   x1  1/16/2013   2
1   B   x1  1/16/2013   2
1   A   x1  1/16/2013   4
2   A   x1  1/23/2013   2
2   B   x2  1/30/2013   2
2   C   x1  2/6/2013    2
2   D   x3  2/13/2013   4
```

I need to transpose by Product, such that all products appear as columns..like below..

```
customerid  Date    Store   A   B   C   D
1   1/2/2013    x1  4           
1   1/9/2013    x2  4   4       
1   1/16/2013   x1  4   2   2   
2   1/23/2013   x1  2           
2   1/30/2013   x2      2       
2   2/6/2013    x1          2   
2   2/13/2013   x3              4
```

Please help! I am trying to work with the transpose function, and i tried unsuccesfully to read through some threads here, but to no avail

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dcast` from "reshape2".

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(mydf, customerid + store + Date ~ product, value.var="Sales")
#   customerid store      Date  A  B  C  D
# 1          1    x1 1/16/2013  4  2  2 NA
# 2          1    X1  1/2/2013  4 NA NA NA
# 3          1    x2  1/9/2013  4  4 NA NA
# 4          2    x1 1/23/2013  2 NA NA NA
# 5          2    x1  2/6/2013 NA NA  2 NA
# 6          2    x2 1/30/2013 NA  2 NA NA
# 7          2    x3 2/13/2013 NA NA NA  4
```

---

If you wanted to have "" instead of `NA`, you can do that too, but note that you would have coerced those columns to `character`.

```
dcast(mydf, customerid + store + Date ~ product, value.var="Sales", fill="")
#   customerid store      Date A B C D
# 1          1    x1 1/16/2013 4 2 2  
# 2          1    X1  1/2/2013 4      
# 3          1    x2  1/9/2013 4 4    
# 4          2    x1 1/23/2013 2      
# 5          2    x1  2/6/2013     2  
# 6          2    x2 1/30/2013   2    
# 7          2    x3 2/13/2013       4
```

---

For a base R solution, you can use `reshape()`:

```
reshape(mydf, direction = "wide", 
        idvar = c("customerid", "store", "Date"), 
        timevar = "product")
#    customerid store      Date Sales.A Sales.B Sales.C Sales.D
# 1           1    X1  1/2/2013       4      NA      NA      NA
# 2           1    x2  1/9/2013       4       4      NA      NA
# 4           1    x1 1/16/2013       4       2       2      NA
# 7           2    x1 1/23/2013       2      NA      NA      NA
# 8           2    x2 1/30/2013      NA       2      NA      NA
# 9           2    x1  2/6/2013      NA      NA       2      NA
# 10          2    x3 2/13/2013      NA      NA      NA       4
```

---

Another possibility is to use `model.matrix` (thanks @Thomas for explaining the `model.matrix` approach in a recent Q & A):

```
# cbind(mydf, model.matrix(~ 0 + product, data = mydf) * mydf$Sales)
#    customerid product store      Date Sales productA productB productC productD
# 1           1       A    X1  1/2/2013     4        4        0        0        0
# 2           1       B    x2  1/9/2013     4        0        4        0        0
# 3           1       A    x2  1/9/2013     4        4        0        0        0
# 4           1       C    x1 1/16/2013     2        0        0        2        0
# 5           1       B    x1 1/16/2013     2        0        2        0        0
# 6           1       A    x1 1/16/2013     4        4        0        0        0
# 7           2       A    x1 1/23/2013     2        2        0        0        0
# 8           2       B    x2 1/30/2013     2        0        2        0        0
# 9           2       C    x1  2/6/2013     2        0        0        2        0
# 10          2       D    x3 2/13/2013     4        0        0        0        4
```

Comment: @SimonO101, I can, but that would then coerce those columns to `character`. In my opinion, not the best idea.

Comment: may be, we could set is.na(df)<-0 for the NA above, if thats what you're asking Simon0101?... but this will be post the dcast function..Believe that shoyuld be fine

Comment: ananda- any reason why my R crashes each time i run the dcast command above?. My dataset has 8 million rows, is that why... If that's the case, can we make this solution any different?

Comment: @kaos1511, does it crash with a warning or are you saying it freezes? `dcast` can sometimes be slow, and if I understand correctly, slows down quickly as the number of combinations increases.

Comment: @kaos1511, if you wanted to set `NA` to zero, just use `dcast(mydf, customerid + store + Date ~ product, value.var="Sales", fill=0)`

Comment: @kaos1511, I don't know if base R would be any more promising for your problem, but I've posted a solution with that.

Comment: Ananda, isnt there anything that mentions that the variable to be transposed is by sales?.. dont see that here in Base R solution

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36646/discussion-between-ananda-mahto-and-kaos1511)

Comment: Error in paste(rep(l, length(lvs)), rep(lvs, each = length(l)), sep = sep) : 
  long vectors not supported yet: memory.c:1569
In addition: Warning message:
In ans * length(l) : NAs produced by integer overflow   I get this error...

Comment: Hi- are there any alternative solutions to this?. I have a huge dataset with 8 MM rows and hence both solutions above crash :(

Comment: Ananda- Suppose i want to tranfer this new dataset with additional columns after tranpose into a dataframe, just Doing something like Output<-dcast(mydf, customerid + store + Date ~ product, value.var="Sales", fill="")
should work right?>... I see that if i do this, i dont see all columns transposed completely... :(.. Wat am i missing?

Comment: i was able to figure out the issue as per my last post:  Output<-dcast(df, CustID+Store+Date ~ product, value.var="Sales",fill=0,function (x) sum (x))